# Why am I unable to send an email order using the Ubercart and Smtp Authentification module?

Tags: emails, ubercart

After Ubercart checkout submitting order, I get this error:

> Unable to send email. Contact the site administrator if the problem
>   persists.

I am using the [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module, I configured it correctly. Test mails work. So the error lies probably within Ubercart.

On Drupal `/admin/reports/dblog`, I get this interesting error log:

> Error on sending e-mail (from admin@xxxxx.com to
>   admin@xxxxx.com.com).

**it tries to send the mail to the sender mail? Very weird!**

How to get this resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the solution using the instructions at "[Drupal – Ubercart and SMTP Authentication Support](https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2013/06/05/drupal-ubercart-and-smtp-authentication-support/)".

1. I installed [Mail System](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) module.
2. In the Mail System configuration, I updated the Cart module class, Order module class and Store module class so that they all use the SmtpMailSystem rather than UbercartMailSystem, as shown in the screenprint below:

   [image]